# Voltage drop on cable

Tags: voltage, cables

I was trying to measure voltage drop caused by length of cables. I generated short high frequency voltage pulse (>200kHz, 70V) and compared the voltage on the generator with the voltage at the end of connected cable.

[image: scheme]

But my results show that when I used a capacitor with 10nF and the cable with length 30m, than the voltage at the end of the cable increased to 130% (with respect to the voltage on the same capacitor attached directly on the generator output.)

How it is possible that the voltage can increase? I would expect that it can only decrease? Is there anything I don't do correctly?

Example (consider only the red lines):
[image: exmaple]
Description of the example: the red crosses represent voltage pulse on the generator and the red solid line represents the voltage on the end of 30m long cable.

When I used capacitor 100nF, then the voltage decreased to 60%. And it was as I expected.

Comment: That seems a very odd way to measure voltage drop... it is broadly proportional to the *current flowing* in the cable as voltage drop is a product of *resistance* and *current*.

Comment: When your power supply is switching, you may get very short overvoltage and undervoltage on the cap. However, we need to see what you're talking bout. Show us scope's output!

Comment: My main goal is not to measure the voltage drop itself. But I only need to know how the cable length affects the voltage on the capacitor. For clarification, I just added the example.

Comment: What does "after the switch" mean? What switch? What is a "high frequency pulse"? A pulse, being a non-periodic signal, can't have a frequency.

Comment: The term "after the switch" is just my internal name, you need not look at it. And each pulse some frequencies, even the non-periodical one (at least in the sense of the Fourier Tansformartion).

Answer (score 4):

Cables don't just have resistance, they have inductance. You've acccidentally built a boost converter; you have an LC circuit which is resonant at about the width of your pulse.

If you want to measure the *resistance* of the cable, use DC. Measuring the characteristic impedance is more complicated. Is that what you actually want.